# Create cron executing node.js file

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, cron

I'm trying to execute a javascript file every two hours. I'm using node.js so I create this cron

```
1 * * * * /usr/bin/node /var/www/html/uniphiData/js/recalculate_points.js
```

My recalculate_ponts.js file is this:

```
var mysql = require('/var/www/html/uniphiData/mysql');

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'HOST',
    user: 'USER',
    password: 'PASS!',
    database: 'DATABASE'
});

connection.connect();

connection.query('SELECT * FROM users', function (err, rows, fields) {
    if (err) throw err;

    rows.forEach(function (row, index) {
        connection.query('SELECT count(*) AS friends FROM users WHERE invitedByFriend = ' + row.ID, function (err2, friends, fields2) {
            if (err2) throw err2;

            var realCountFriends = friends[0].friends;
            friends = friends[0].friends * 50;

            var id = '%;' + row.ID + ';%';

            connection.query('SELECT SUM(pointsPerShare) AS shareEvent FROM events WHERE shared LIKE "' + id + '"', function (err3, pointsPerSharing, fields3) {
                if (err3) throw err3;

                if (pointsPerSharing[0].shareEvent == null)
                    pointsPerSharing = 0;
                else
                    pointsPerSharing = pointsPerSharing[0].shareEvent;

                connection.query('SELECT SUM(e.pointsEntry) AS entry FROM orders o, events e WHERE o.used = 1 AND o.userID = ' + row.ID + ' AND o.eventID = e.ID', function (err4, pointsEntry, fields4) {

                    if (err4) throw err4;

                    if (pointsEntry[0].entry == null)
                        pointsEntry = 0;
                    else
                        pointsEntry = pointsEntry[0].entry;


                    connection.query('SELECT SUM(e.pointsPrepay) AS purchase FROM orders o, events e WHERE o.guestList = 0 AND o.cheapList = 0 AND o.userID = ' + row.ID + ' AND o.eventID = e.ID', function (err5, pointsPrepay, fields5) {
                        if (err5) throw err5;

                        if (pointsPrepay[0].purchase == null)
                            pointsPrepay = 0;
                        else
                            pointsPrepay = pointsPrepay[0].purchase;

                        var shareApp = row.quantitySharedApp * 20;
                        var newUser = 50;

                        var realCount = friends + pointsPerSharing + pointsEntry + pointsPrepay + shareApp + newUser;
                        var difference = realCount - row.totalPoints;

                        if (difference != 0) {
                            connection.query('UPDATE users SET points = points + ' + difference + ', totalPoints = ' + realCount + ', monthPoints = monthPoints + ' + difference + ', friendsInvited = ' + realCountFriends + ' WHERE ID = ' + row.ID, function (err6, changePoints, fields6) {

                                if (index == rows.length - 1) {
                                    connection.end();
                                }
                            })
                        } else {

                            if (index == rows.length - 1) {
                                connection.end();
                            }
                        }

                    })

                })


            })


        })
    })

});
```

The log in cron is this:

```
Nov 17 14:55:01 name CRON[4677]: (root) CMD (/usr/local/rtm/bin/rtm 14 > /dev/null 2> /dev/null)
```

Of course is not executing the javascript file and I know the script works because I execute it without the cron.
I don't know what I'm doing wrong but I search in internet and I try to put the absolute route and the relative route, but nothing happens.

Thanks a million

Comment: Do you really need the whole file to be run every two hours, or would only scheduling your query (by and in the code) suffice? In the latter case, you could take a look at the [`cron`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron) module.

Comment: @schroffl yes I need to run all the script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an bash script (.sh) that executes the .js file. You will call the .sh file with your cron.

```
1 * * * * /path/to/file.sh
```

The .sh file can look like this:

`#!/bin/bash
cd "$(dirname "$0")"
node ./app.js`

app.js is obviously your javascript file that is in the same folder as your .sh file

Comment: I put the same but the cron like 1 * * * * to execute every minute to test now and it is not working.

Comment: @Ary what does the log say?

Comment: I wrote in the question:
Nov 17 14:55:01 name CRON[4677]: (root) CMD (/usr/local/rtm/bin/rtm 14 > /dev/null 2> /dev/null)

Comment: have you tried running different crons without node? I think this is more a general cron problem than something to do with node

Comment: If everything fails, just make your app run permanently and time it with https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cron.

Comment: I can't leave the computer on always